# instance method not found when using more than one parameter

Tags: objective-c

My question is about a case where things work fine for a method with one parameter, but not for two. The code comes from Apple animation sample code.

the main view object, (self), has readonly reference to an abstract superclass object, s.

It can call methods on an instance that inherits from the superclass like this:

```
[self.s myMethod:param1];
```

and it works fine.

However, when I try:

```
[self.s anotherMethod:param1 secondParam:param2];
```

I get the compile error:

> Semantic Issue > Instance method '-anotherMethod:secondParam:' not found (return type
>   defaults to 'id')

Both the methods have return type - (void).

Everything is declared and defined in the same way for the first case and the second.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

(I don't really want to resort to bundling up parameters into a single object!)

---

amendment with example added below

declarations like this in .h files of superclass and inherited class

for the super class:

```
@interface SuperClass : NSObject
{
...
}
...
- (void) myMethod:(SomeObject *) param1;
- (void) anotherMethod:(SomeObject *) param1: (int) param2;
@end
```

for the inherited class:

```
#import "SuperClass.h"
@interface InheritedClass : SuperClass
{
...
}
...
- (void) myMethod:(SomeObject *) param1;
- (void) anotherMethod:(SomeObject *) param1: (int) param2;
@end
```

implementations in .m file of each class

have tried adding this to the inherited class .m file.

```
@interface InheritedClass ()
- (void) anotherMethod:(SomeObject *) param1: (int) param2;
@end
```

Comment: Is there a declaration of `-anotherMethod:secondParam:` in the `@interface` of `s`'s class?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here. It seems like you understand the issue but you are *unhappy* about it (?). So yeah - if a method takes one param and you provide two, it is going to throw an error. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you post the @interface declaration for both methods? Are they both in the header file?

Comment: there is a declaration in the '@interface' of the .m file of the superclass and the class that inherits from it.

Comment: It is not the case that I am calling the first example method using two parameters instead of one

Comment: both methods are declared in the same manner in the header file.

Comment: If the methods are declared in the @interface class extension in the .m file, it wont be visible in subclasses or other classes that access this class.

Comment: a declaration for the 2nd method was added to the @interface class extension in the .m file of both the superclass and the inherited class after reading some other answers here. It did not help so i have removed it.

Comment: Clean the code once before running it.

Comment: This isn't answerable without you including the _actual_ interface(s) of the class(es) you're talking about. You're being too vague, and some of the things you've said ("If I change the scope of the superclass to @public in the interface of the view,") are literally unintelligible.

Comment: Cleaning does not help it to compile.

Comment: Can we see example code for each @interface and which .h and .m files they sit in, and what/where the #import statements are?

Comment: Many thanks to all for helping out here. I was horribly confused for a while, its much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call:

```
[self.s anotherMethod:param1 secondParam:param2];
```

...means the method name is `anotherMethod:secondParam:`.

This declaration:

```
- (void) anotherMethod:(SomeObject *) param1: (int) param2;
```

...does not have the same name.

Is it possible that you meant to say:

```
- (void) anotherMethod:(SomeObject *)param1 secondParam:(int)param2;
```

?

Comment: Yes, that is it exactly. Thank you very much, I am most grateful.